# window.document.addEventListener behavior inconsistent and appears wrong (JS)

Tags: javascript

My script takes CSV input and from that finds a user's name.  It then creates a URL given the user's name.
From there, the script opens the user's URL, collects some data about the user, and puts that info into an array for later output.

My problem is with the window.document.addEventListener.  the specific code line is as follows:

element.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",getSomething(),false);

The strange behavior is as follows:
With the statement above, the listener fires and getSomething() code begins execution.  However, the page is not loaded.  in the console I can see that the page contents are simply nothing more than an empty body.

Changing "getSomething()" to "getSomething" (in the addEventListener code line) causes the pages to eventually load, however, the getSomething function is never executed (apparently addEventListener did not fire.)

some introduction to the code that follows:
variable testURLs is an array containing a user's URL. 
function controlOpenWindows() is not fully set up but its intent is to determine when a window is ready to close, and when data from as many as four opened windows is collected, all four will close and four more will open.  four is arbitrary.  there are over 900 user URLs so just limiting number open at any one time.

The function that closes the previously opened windows makes the call to open more windows.

Please note that you would need a login id and password to open specific user pages.  so passing the URL to you in this post would not be helpful.  I'm hoping you can help without that specific info.

```
function closeOpenedWindow(index){
     switch (index) {
       case 0:
        blnZero=true;
        break;
       case 1:
        blnOne=true;
        break;
       case 2:
        blnTwo=true;
        break;
       case 3:
        blnThree=true;
     }
     if (blnZero===true && blnOne===true && blnTwo===true && blnThree===true) {
      for (p=0; p<4; p++) {
        openedWindow[p].close();
        count +=1;
      controlOpenWindows();
     }
      }
  }
    function controlOpenWindows() {
     debugger;
      testURLs=[];
      blnZero=false;
      blnOne=true;
      blnTwo=true;
      blnThree=true;
      if (editorProfileURL.length>=4) {
        testURLs[0]= editorProfileURL.shift();
        testURLs[1] =editorProfileURL.shift();
        testURLs[2]=editorProfileURL.shift();
        testURLs[3]=editorProfileURL.shift();
      } else {
        for (n=0; n<editorProfileURL.length; n++) {
            testURLs[n]=editorProfileURL[n];
        }
      }
      testURLs.forEach(openWindow);
    }
    controlOpenWindows();
    function openWindow(element1, index1, array1) {
     openedWindow[index1]= window.open(element1);
    }
    function loaded(element, index, array) {
      element.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getSomething(), false);
    }
    openedWindow.forEach(loaded);
function getSomething() {
      debugger;
      var whichPage=this.document.URL;
      function whichIndex(element, index, array) {
        if (element.document.URL==whichPage) {
         return element.document.URL;
        }
      }
      var foundIndex=openedWindow.findIndex(whichIndex);
      var reg=/The page you were looking for doesn*/g;
      if (openedWindow[0].document.getElementsByClassName("container not-found").length>0) {
        if(openedWindow[foundIndex].document.getElementsByClassName("container not-found")[foundIndex].innerHTML.match(reg)) {
          closeOpenedWindow(foundIndex);
        }
      } else {
        var firstEdit=openedWindow[foundIndex].document.getElementsByClassName("user-last-edit")[0].innerHTML;
        var lastEditDaysAgo=openedWindow[foundIndex].document.getElementsByClassName("transaction-header-time")[0].innerHTML;
        var rank=openedWindow[foundIndex].doucment.getElementsByClassName("user-rank")[0].innerHTML;
        var editCount=openedWindow[foundIndex].document.getElementsByClassName("user-stats-value")[1].innerHTML;
        updatedEditorInfo.push();
        updatedEditorInfo.push(firstEdit + ",");
        updatedEditorInfo.push(lastEditDaysAgo+ ",");
        updatedEdtiorInfo.push(rank + ",");
        updatedEditorInfo.push(editoCount + ",");
        updatedEditorInfo.push("\n");
        console.log(updatedEditorInfo);
        alert(updatedEditorInfo);
        //closeOpenedWindow();
        //controlOpenWindows();
      }
      closeOpenedWindow(foundIndex);
      controlOpenWindows();
    }
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You, like many many others, are *calling* `getSomething()` and passing its **return value** (ie. `undefined`) to the handler.

Comment: You are calling the function, not assigning a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the function instead of calling it directly:

```
element.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",getSomething,false);
```

Comment: I've tried the code exactly as you state above: "element.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getSomething, false) and as I stated above, the page loads but the listener never fires.